Running nmap script on a filtered port
I'm trying to scan for smb port (445) on a windows machine using nmap, it keep showing that the port is filtered but after using -sF flag I managed to get that the port is open but it's not runnig the script it just shows it's an open|filtered port without running the script, I hope that the image will explain more:
sudo nmap -sF --script +smb2-security-mode.nse 192.168.184.135 -p 445 -Pn

log:
Starting Nmap 7.94SVN ( https://nmap.org ) at 2024-06-06 10:06 EDT
Nmap scan report for 192.168.184.135
Host is up (0.00026s latency).

PORT    STATE         SERVICE
445/tcp open|filtered microsoft-ds
MAC Address:00:0C:29:8A:10:17 (VMware)

Host script results:
|_smb2-security-mode: SMB: Couldn't find a valid port to check

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 1.45 seconds


Did you use capital P ?
sudo nmap -sF --script=smb2-security-mode.nse 192.168.184.135 -p 445

try this

Judging from the question's second paragraph, the last two parameters were -p 445 -Pn, so the lower-case p was used to specify a port and the capital p was for another argument.
